# My own interesting puzzle

Tags: pattern

I’ve come out one fun puzzle for you all to solve

NITLKVXW    ==> (>,<,X,<,>,>>,<,?,?,?,?)

What’s the symbols in four question marks?

Hint: Turn

Comment: It sure looks like seaching for a song in a casette tape

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> (>,<,X,<,>,>>,<,>,X,>,<) Because, we just continue the sequence in reverse as the hint is to **turn**

Comment: sorry wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry too. I’m.